# Understanding the internal forces in a rotating bar

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, integration, elasticity

I seem to have many misunderstandings about  a [bar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379748/rotation-of-non-rigid-bodies-centrifugal-effect) rotating at a constant angular velocity $\omega$ in a horizontal plane. The bar has a square section $S_0$ and is of length $2L$. The distance from the axis of rotation is $z$. I am tasked with finding the expression for the stress, $\sigma(z)$, resulting from simple traction, assuming that the section $S_0$ does not vary. In order to do that, I first have to find the force, $F(z)$, which I assume is the internal force.

In the solution, it is stated that: $F(z)=\int_{z}^{L} a(z')dm = \int_{z}^{L} \omega^2 z' \rho dz' = ...$

What I do not understand is the choice of the bounds of the integral: why are we only considering the mass between $z$ and the extremity $L$ of the bar? I suppose that the mass in $[z,L]$ is the mass pulling at the section of the bar at z (supposedly due to the centrifugal effect). But then wouldn't the mass between $0$ and $z$ also contribute by pushing the section in the same direction? Also, why are we neglecting the other extremity of the bar?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good trick to remember when analyzing continuous masses is to think about what happens in the much simpler case of finite masses. For instance, replace the rod of length $L$ with three sections of equal parts of length $p = L/3$ and place a masses $m_a, m_b, m_c$ at the end of each part:
[image: a rotating bar of three masses]

Then the sums of forces $\Sigma F_r = - m \omega ^2 r$ on each mass are:
$$ T_2 - T_1 = - m_a \omega ^2 p$$
$$ T_3 - T_2 = - m_b \omega ^2 (2p)$$
$$-T_3 = - m_c \omega ^2 (3p) $$

Solving for the three different tensions:
$$ T_3 = 3 m_c p \omega ^2 $$
$$ T_2 = (3 m_c + 2 m_b) p \omega^2 $$
$$ T_1 = (3 m_c + 2 m_b + m_a) p \omega^2 $$

So clearly the tension in each part only depends on the mass beyond that part. This is why your limits of integration run from $[z,L]$. You don't include $[0,z]$ because those masses' rotations aren't being supported by the tension (stress) at that point.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a force balance on the short section of rod situated between $z$ and $z+\Delta z$, you obtain:  $$F(z+\Delta z)\mathbf{i}_r-F(z)\mathbf{i}_r=-\rho \omega^2z\Delta z \mathbf{i}_r$$where F(z) is the tension in the rod at radial location z.  Dividing by $\Delta z$ and taking the limit as $\Delta z$ approaches zero yields:  $$\frac{dF}{dz}=-\rho \omega^2z$$Integrating this equation from z to L then yields:  $$F(L)-F(z)=-\frac{\rho \omega^2}{2}(L^2-z^2)$$But, the tension in the rod at the end z = L is equal to zero (F(L)=0).  Therefore, $$F(z)=\frac{\rho \omega^2}{2}(L^2-z^2)$$